# Async React - React Suspense - Component is rendering twice sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying the new react features like `useEffect` hook, lazy/suspense and `react-cache` and I am confused about the usage.

I have created a codesandbox and you must be able to witness multiple button label changes sometimes on click;

https://codesandbox.io/s/m4r69wm6z8

The sandbox displays a button and it should fetch the button label from backend upon clicking. I have simulated this by implementing the `unstable_createResource` with a promise wrapped around setTimeout.

It happens sometimes only in the sandbox. But in my project there are tons of buttons like this and the duplicate rendering happens almost all the time.

[image: Replicating Bug]

Comment: Its is called only once on prop change, check https://codesandbox.io/s/82mx0w61mj. If you can create a reproducible demo, it will help in debugging

Comment: I understand. Will add codesandbox with details soon

Comment: The codesandbox you linked just shows a loading label followed by a label change on click once which I think is an expected behavior

Comment: Actually, I'm currently modifying the question with additional details. If you click the button many times, it sometime renders twice changing two labels. Thank you for the response and checking out sandbox though

Comment: I can see that behavior, however, it is related to Suspense rather than the hooks, since its executing correctly. Also I don't see any point on why you would set loading state to true on every count change.

Comment: Updated question details. This isn't my exact project just a replica. Upon clicking the button, label must be fetched form backend. Hence I'm setting loading state to true, so that backend fetch happens again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184330/discussion-between-deadfish-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: Suspense for Data-fetching is not yet stable and even react-cache is highly unstable. react just published a roadmap for its release. I guess you must wait till its ready to use it in production without such glitches that you experience in your demo. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/11/27/react-16-roadmap.html#react-169-suspense-for-data-fetching-mid-2019